# How to place the text of a Row at its bottom?

Tags: flutter

Hi so currently i have a card that looks like this:

[image: Card currently]

And i want to change it so the text that says test is at the bottom of the card, like below:
[image]

Also if you see i added a arrow on the bottom line as well which is where i would like to add a button.

The code i have currently is below:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 160,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: tap,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 2,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(img),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ))),
                ),
                Flexible(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 5, 2, 5),
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                              Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black)),
                              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                              Center(
                                child: Text("Header", style: TextStyle(color: fontSize: 35)),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5.0),

                      ]),
                    )),

                Center(
                  child: Text('test'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

How could i do this?

Comment: Well, rows are horizontal and columns are vertical. You could place a row as a child of your Column (right after SizedBox). In this row you can first put your 'test' Text and then your button. By doing this you should get something close to what you need, and you can play around with the spacing properties to get the exact result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Make effort the next time ;)

```
Card(
  // ...
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Flexible(
        flex: 2,
        // ... your image section
      ),
      Flexible(
        flex: 3,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  // ... your title
                  // ... your header
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("Test"),
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("Your Button"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Well i tried like this also however even in this the text in the row will not always stay at the bottom. The row will start wherever the SizedBox ends. I want it to stick to the bottom Sure i could increase the sized of the sized box but then for some cards where the text at the top is more, i would get overflow.

Comment: There is not any `SizedBox` in my code. Redesign it with what I posted

Comment: I did but even without it its the same. The text doesnt stick to the bottom. Sized box would make it appear that way by adding some space there. I have managed to fix it anyways. I kept the row, but added the title in a container, and then put the header text in a container and then expanded.